# Reinstall macOS Mojave on MacBook Pro with Windows installed

Tags: windows, install, mojave

I was installing Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro without Boot Camp, because it's SSD capacity is only 128 GB. But now I need to revert back to macOS Mojave. Is it possible?

I tried downloading the installer for macOS Mojave and make a USB bootable drive, but somehow my MacBook doesn't recognize the USB at first boot (holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key).

Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) You can attempt to start your Mac in Recovery mode by following [these](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204904) instructions. macOS can also be installed via Internet recovery.

Comment: Even if i totally removed the macOS before?

Comment: Yes. Internet recovery download the macOS installer over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible and very simple to reinstall macOS Mojave on your MacBook Pro. An easy approach would be to perform the Internet recovery. Using Internet recovery, your MacBook Pro connects to Apple's servers, and download and install macOS over the Internet.

To learn more about installing macOS via Internet Recovery, you can follow the instructions in the Apple Support document:

- [How to reinstall macOS from macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204904)